# Swift: Delete photo in iOS Action Extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, ios-extensions, phphotolibrary

So i'm developing an app to let user select a few photos in the system Photo Library then using the **Action Extension** via the share sheet to delete some of those photos.

I was using `extensionContext.inputItems` to get the URLs of the selected photos:

```
let extensionItems = (self.extensionContext!.inputItems as! [NSExtensionItem]).first!
let attachments = extensionItems.attachments! as! [NSItemProvider]

for provider in attachments {
    provider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeImage as String, options: nil) {
        (imageURL, error) in
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Then i was using `PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets` to delete photos by it's URL

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    let imageAssetToDelete = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: imageURLs, options: nil)
    PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(imageAssetToDelete)
}, completionHandler: {success, error in
    if success {
        print("success")
    } else {
        print(error!)
    }
})
```

The "success" was printed to the console but the photo deletion doesn't requested (that delete photo alert [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j62pd.png) doesn't shown)

So i inspected the variable `imageAssetToDelete` but it prints:

```
<PHFetchResult: 0x28188b200> count=0
```

the `PHFetchResult` has no items.

Which part went wrong?

Comment: What is the action extension for? If you are in your own app, just delete the photos. If you are appearing in an activity view in someone else's app, you _can't_ delete the photos.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling for days trying to find out what happened, but in my case the thing appeared to be extremely simple. In fact, `changeBlock` is called asynchronously (what is clearly stated in documentation) while in my code the array with assets is emptied right after (actually before) request. Code:

```swift
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    // called when array is already empty
    PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(self.assetsToDelete as NSArray)
})
// called first
assetsToDelete.removeAll()
```

So the solution in my case was to simply move `.removeAll()` in `completionHandler`:

```swift
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(self.assetsToDelete as NSArray)
}, completionHandler: { c, _ in
    if c {
         self.assetsToDelete.removeAll()
    }
})
```